# After SignalR connection error continue process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

My server Hub is sending data to all clients continously. And my client appliction gets data.

```
    $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:40874/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.start();
    var hub = $.connection.messages;
    messages.client.newMessage = function(mes){ // show message }
```

When my server down, thi client side application console writes error.

> GET http://localhost:60874/Api/Messages/GetMessages
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This message writes continously on console. I do not want to do this. It should write only one time.

And when I restart the server, the application does not listen anymore. I should refresh the client page. Why?